# Django recursive serializing

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have models like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...some fields here

class B(models.Model):
    ...some fields here
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=CASCADE)

class C(models.Model):
    ...some fields here
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=CASCADE)

...
```

And I want my API endpoint to return something like this

```
{
  ...some fields here
  b: [
  {
    ...some field here
    c: [{...}, {...} ...]
  },
  {
    ...some field here
    c: [{...}, {...} ...]
  }
  ...
  ]
}
```

I know I can do something like this:

```
class Bserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  c = Cserializer(source="c_set", many=True, read_only=True,)

  class Meta:
      model = B
      fields = [...some fields, "c"]

class Aserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  b = Bserializer(source="b_set", many=True, read_only=True,)

  class Meta:
      model = A
      fields = [...some fields, "b"]
```

But if this goes deeper or/and models have more foreign keys it starts to become really complicated. Is there a way to add recursively all instances referencing the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `depth` value in the serializer `Meta` class, however, this won't' work if you want to customize any part of the nested data, as this will automatically create model serializers (with all fields) for nested relations. Check docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization)

```
class Aserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
      model = A
      fields = [...some fields, "b"]
      depth = 2
```

The bottom line, if you don't do any customization of the nested serializers, use it, otherwise, stick with custom serializers for each of the relations. But I'll suggest keeping the nested data at a minimum as it will impact performance